# Running python script via ssh connection

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a python script(python 2.7) on my computer at work and everything worked perfect. Now I tried to start it from home. 
I used a ssh connection to login but I noticed, that every `import` command doesnt work if the imported project is not in the same dictionary. For example, if i use `ipython` in terminal at work i can write `import aligner`, but if I try it from my laptop via ssh connection it doesnt work, the project i want to import needs to be in the same dictionary. 
I need a solution without moving all projects into one dictionary

Comment: You can clarify your question by describing what you've done to attempt to fix the problem. For example, are you sure you have the same environment (PYTHONPATH, etc) when connecting via ssh as when logging in via a terminal directly?

Comment: The problem is that i have no idea how to fix it, because I am new into Linux and Terminal things. I thought if I use `ssh -X username@host` I can use the Terminal like I use it at work, but it seems like there is a different.

Comment: Without getting into too much detail, there are various differences between the typical unix/linux shells (bash, ksh, sh etc), and also between how your environment - variables that affect various unixy programs - are set up. You can add to your question to help others. Useful information will be: what shell you are running in both environments; the contents of your shell's resource file (e.g. .bashrc) and profile (e.g. .bash_profile), and the output of 'env' when logged in via both methods. You may also want to read a good tutorial on your shell and how to configure it.

Comment: In the spirit of giving you a fish, rather than teaching you how to fish: echo $PYTHONPATH in your shell when logged in to the terminal directly vs. logged in via ssh.